# A request to script a stored procedure return values in process query

Tags: stored-procedures

A request to script a scored proc that returns this :

Request

1. when you pass null return all
2. and field can search
3. an combination can search

Code:

```
@AccountNo varchar(30) = null,
@DateLogged datetime = null,
@ReferenceNo varchar (50) = null,
@ErfNo varchar (45) = null,
@Surname varchar (255) = null,
@Name varchar (255) = null,
@IdentityNo varchar (13) = null,

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_case]
(
     @AccountNo varchar(30) = null,
     @DateLogged datetime = null,
     @ReferenceNo varchar (50) = null,
     @ErfNo varchar (45) = null,
     @Surname varchar (255) = null,
     @Name varchar (255) = null,
     @ProcessInstanceId varchar (50) = null,
     @IdentityNo varchar (13) = null,
     @Summary varchar (max) = null,
     @Suspend varchar (10) = null,
     @Notes varchar (max) = null,
     @RatesNo varchar (30) = null,
     @Status varchar (50) = null
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER, RECOMPILE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        dbo.Cases.DateLogged,
        dbo.Cases.ReferenceNo,
        dbo.Account.AccountNo,
        dbo.Customer.RatesNo,
        dbo.Customer.IdentityNo,
        dbo.Account.ErfNo,
        dbo.Customer.Surname,
        dbo.Customer.Name,
        dbo.Cases.ProcessInstanceId,
        dbo.Cases.Status,
        dbo.Cases.Summary,
        dbo.Cases.Suspend,
        dbo.Cases.Notes
    FROM
        [ICSM_CORRES].[dbo].[Cases]
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].Customer ON dbo.Cases.CustomerId = dbo.Cases.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Account ON dbo.Customer.AccountNoId = dbo.Account.AccountNoId
    WHERE
        dbo.Account.AccountNo = @AccountNo
        OR dbo.Customer.RatesNo = @RatesNo
        OR dbo.Cases.DateLogged = @DateLogged
        OR dbo.Cases.ReferenceNo = @ReferenceNo
        OR dbo.Customer.IdentityNo = @IdentityNo
        OR dbo.Account.ErfNo = @ErfNo
        OR dbo.Customer.Surname = @Surname
        OR dbo.Customer.Name = @Name
        OR dbo.Cases.ProcessInstanceId = @ProcessInstanceId
        OR dbo.Cases.Status = @Status
        OR dbo.Cases.Summary = @Summary
        OR dbo.Cases.Suspend = @Suspend
        OR dbo.Cases.Notes = @Notes
```

Answer (score 0):

- "When you pass null return all" => `WHERE col = ISNULL(@argument, col)`
- Rest of conditions should work, but the performance of initial query won't be best (multiple join and multiple OR in where clause) probably cause full table scans.
- You can also alias fully-qualified names like `[dbo].Customer AS c` and then use `dbo.Customer.Surname` simply as `c.Surname`
- Probably you have error in JOIN ON (the same table and column) `[dbo].Customer ON dbo.Cases.CustomerId = dbo.Cases.CustomerId`

.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_case]
(
     @AccountNo varchar(30) = null,
     @DateLogged datetime = null,
     @ReferenceNo varchar (50) = null,
     @ErfNo varchar (45) = null,
     @Surname varchar (255) = null,
     @Name varchar (255) = null,
     @ProcessInstanceId varchar (50) = null,
     @IdentityNo varchar (13) = null,
     @Summary varchar (max) = null,
     @Suspend varchar (10) = null,
     @Notes varchar (max) = null,
     @RatesNo varchar (30) = null,
     @Status varchar (50) = null
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER, RECOMPILE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        dbo.Cases.DateLogged,
        dbo.Cases.ReferenceNo,
        dbo.Account.AccountNo,
        dbo.Customer.RatesNo,
        dbo.Customer.IdentityNo,
        dbo.Account.ErfNo,
        dbo.Customer.Surname,
        dbo.Customer.Name,
        dbo.Cases.ProcessInstanceId,
        dbo.Cases.Status,
        dbo.Cases.Summary,
        dbo.Cases.Suspend,
        dbo.Cases.Notes
    FROM
        [ICSM_CORRES].[dbo].[Cases]
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].Customer ON dbo.Cases.CustomerId = dbo.Cases.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Account ON dbo.Customer.AccountNoId = dbo.Account.AccountNoId
    WHERE
        dbo.Account.AccountNo = ISNULL(@AccountNo, dbo.Account.AccountNo)
        OR dbo.Customer.RatesNo = ISNULL(@RatesNo, dbo.Customer.RatesNo)
        OR dbo.Cases.DateLogged = ISNULL(@DateLogged, dbo.Cases.DateLogged)
        OR dbo.Cases.ReferenceNo = ISNULL(@ReferenceNo, dbo.Cases.ReferenceNo)
        OR dbo.Customer.IdentityNo = ISNULL(@IdentityNo, dbo.Customer.IdentityNo)
        /* ... and so on */
```